# From SQL to Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

i'm trying to rewrite the following query in oracle
i wrote it using sql server

```
--check if there is no exam at the same time
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT DISTINCT 'TRUE'
    FROM FinalExams
    WHERE ClassID = @pClassID
        AND SectionID = @pSectionID
        AND ExamDate = @pExamDate
        AND @pStartHoure BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, - 1, StartHoure)
            AND DATEADD(minute, - 1, FinishHoure)
        AND @pFinishHoure NOT BETWEEN DATEADD(minute, - 1, StartHoure)
            AND DATEADD(minute, - 1, FinishHoure)
        OR StartHoure > @pStartHoure
        AND FinishHoure < @pFinishHoure
    )
```

can anybody help ?

Comment: What is the issue here? you have an error?

Comment: Please post your attempts to convert this to Oracle SQL.

Comment: unfortunately i don't have any oracle experience i just need to run this query at oracle sql developer

Comment: Are you running it as a standalone query, or in a PL/SQL block? Or is it a part of another query?

Comment: @Przemyslaw Kruglej its part of Procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would accomplish it in Oracle:

```
DECLARE
  v_cnt NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(1)
    INTO v_cnt
    FROM dual
  WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM FinalExams
    WHERE ClassID = p_ClassID
        AND SectionID = p_SectionID
        AND ExamDate = p_ExamDate
        AND p_StartHoure BETWEEN StartHoure - INTERVAL '1' MINUTE
            AND FinishHoure - INTERVAL '1' MINUTE
        AND p_FinishHoure NOT BETWEEN StartHoure - INTERVAL '1' MINUTE
            AND FinishHoure - INTERVAL '1' MINUTE
        OR StartHoure > p_StartHoure
        AND FinishHoure < p_FinishHoure
    );

  IF v_cnt > 0 THEN
    -- your code here
  END IF;
END;
```

Of course, this is just an example. I assume `@pClassID` and others are variables. Try this approach in your procedure.